# Can distributive law be applied into if-then and only-if statements?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Are the two statements can be logically equivalent, just like in OR, AND expressions?

[(p ^ q) ↔ r] = [(p ↔ r) ^ (q ↔ r)]

[(p ^ q) ⇒ r] = [(p ⇒ r) ^ (q ⇒ r)]

Comment: See [Distributivity and Truth functional connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Truth_functional_connectives)

Comment: For the second one, you can easily check that the truth assignment $v(p)= \text T$ and $v(q)=v(r)= \text F$ falsifies the equivalence.

Comment: Similar for the first one.

Comment: Hi. Care to elaborate a bit more so that I could understand your explanation?

Comment: Do you know truth tables ?

Comment: yes. It's to prove the logical equivalent. I can directly use distributive law in the case of OR and AND expressions without using truth table to evaluate. But in this case, it is IF and ONLY-IF statement.

Comment: Perfect : use them to check the equivalences.

Comment: so IF, ONLY-IF, and XOR can't use the distributive law to check the equivalences right?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a mess. Some hold and some don't. Below shows you what holds as an equivalence ($\Leftrightarrow$) and what does not ($\not \Leftrightarrow$):

$(P \land Q) \to R \not \Leftrightarrow (P \to R) \land (Q \to R)$

$(P \lor Q) \to R \Leftrightarrow (P \to R) \lor (Q \to R)$

$P \to (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \to Q) \land (P \to R)$

$P \to (Q \lor R) \not \Leftrightarrow (P \to Q) \lor (P \to R)$

$P \leftrightarrow (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \leftrightarrow Q) \land (P \leftrightarrow R)$

$P \leftrightarrow (Q \lor R) \not \Leftrightarrow (P \leftrightarrow Q) \lor (P \leftrightarrow R)$

$P \land (Q \to R) \not \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \to (P \land R)$

$P \lor (Q \to R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \to (P \land R)$

$P \land (Q \leftrightarrow R) \not \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow  (P \land R)$

$P \lor (Q \leftrightarrow  R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow  (P \land R)$